# Does ProGuard version 5.3.2 support JavaFx?

Tags: java, swing, javafx, proguard

I thought it should support Java 8's JavaFx, but when I ran it, I got the following :

```
ProGuard, version 5.3.2
Reading input...
Reading program jar [C:\Dir_myApp\dist\App.jar]
Reading library jar [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\lib\rt.jar]
Reading library jar [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\lib\jce.jar]
Reading library jar [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\lib\jfxswt.jar]
Reading library jar [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\lib\jfr.jar]
Initializing...
Warning: App: can't find referenced class javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel
Warning: App: can't find referenced class javafx.scene.media.Media
```

I included jfxswt.jar & jfr.jar because they seem like JavaFx jar files, what do I need to do to make it work with [javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel] and [javafx.embed.swing.Media] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer, I don't need the 2 jar files : jfxswt.jar & jfr.jar.

But I do need to include : /lib/ext/jfxrt.jar to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use ProGuard and JavaFX, you might want to take a look into a example-project from the javaf-maven-plugin:

https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin/tree/master/src/it/08-build-with-proguard

Following configuration is used:

```
-dontoptimize

# Save meta-data for stack traces
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# Rename FXML files together with related views
-adaptresourcefilenames **.fxml,**.png,**.css
-adaptresourcefilecontents **.fxml
-adaptclassstrings

# Keep all annotations and meta-data
-keepattributes *Annotation*,Signature,EnclosingMethod

# Keep entry-point class
-keep class com.zenjava.test.javafx_and_proguard.MainApp {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}

# Keep all classes inside application
-keep,allowobfuscation class com.zenjava.test.javafx_and_proguard.** {
}

# Keep names of fields marked with @FXML attribute
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @javafx.fxml.FXML *;
}
```

EDIT: for documentation-completeness, the missing pom-configuration-part

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
    <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.10</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>proguard</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <proguardVersion>5.2</proguardVersion>
        <libs>
            <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
            <lib>${java.home}/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar</lib>
            <lib>${java.home}/lib/jce.jar</lib>
        </libs>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
            <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

**DISCLAIMER:** I'm the maintainer of the javafx-maven-plugin ;)